# How to use CSS inside serverfbml tag?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I am trying to develop a iframe based facebook application using ROR

here is my code for view

```
  %fb:serverfbml.fbml-server
    %script{:type => "text/fbml"}
      %fb:fbml
        = stylesheet_link_tag "http://serveraddress/stylesheets/main.css"
        .title Check the Deck
```

the css simply doesn;t apply

i have accessed the css using absolute address and it has all the css for my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't link to a css in serverfbml, however you can embed the actual css directly into the serverfbml block.  They will be processed and recognized - but they need to be inside the  block.

Comment: you mean I should use inline css inside serverfbml tag? or you mean copy paste the whole css block for the view inside serverfbml tag?

Comment: ok i found the solution ... http://serversideguy.com/2010/09/21/external-css-stylesheet-on-static-fbml-page/